# Difference between R base function `identical`l and `testthat` `expect_identical`?

Tags: r, testthat

### Context

```
xml_reserved_chars_to_named_entities <- function(string) {

  if(string == "" || identical(string, character(0))) return("")
  if(length(string) > 1) sapply(string, xml_reserved_chars_to_named_entities)

  chars <- unlist(strsplit(string, ""))
  pattern <- c('<', '&', '>', "'", '"')
  replacement <- c('&lt;', '&amp;', '&gt;', '&apos;', '&quot;')

  result = chars
  for (i in seq_along(pattern)) {
    result[grep(pattern[i], chars)] = replacement[i]
  }
  paste0(result)
}
```

### Problem

The function above, returns `TRUE` on `identical(xml_reserved_chars_to_named_entities("''"), "&apos;&apos;")`

but fails to pass the following test (using `testthat` package) with:

```
test_that("xml_reserved_chars_to_named_entities",
{
     expect_identical(xml_reserved_chars_to_named_entities("''"), "&apos;&apos;")
}
)
```

I was expecting it to pass that test as it gives `TRUE` with `identical`'s call. Why is not that so?

Here is `testthat` feedback on that test:

```
Failed -------------------------------------------------------------------------
1. Failure: xml_reserved_chars_to_named_entities (@test-utils.R#48) ------------
xml_reserved_chars_to_named_entities("''") not identical to "&apos;&apos;".
Lengths differ: 2 vs 1
```

### Version details

My R version is `3.3.0` and that of `testthat` is `1.0.2`. Help is appreciated.

Comment: your `paste0` would either need to be `paste0(result, collapse = '')` or you need to split the `"&apos;&apos;"` into two `c("&apos;", "&apos;")` also your problem returns false for me, not true

Comment: @rawr: Ok, thanks. I see your point. But I still do not see why `identical` and `expect_identical` are behaving differently in this case.

Comment: I get `FALSE` with `identical`. You might want to run it again.

Comment: my bad... indeed the function I was calling is of a previous version... sorry guys.

Comment: @plant because your current function gives me `c("&apos;", "&apos;")` and you are testing for equality with `"&apos;&apos;"`